# Parse Notification

Tags: ios, parse-platform, notifications, channel

I'm trying to register a device in several Parse channels, but does not work and do not know what I'm doing wrong.

In my table Parse does not appear that the device is in these channels

This is executed when you press a button.

```
[currentInstallation addUniqueObject:@"CocaCola" forKey:@"channels"];
[currentInstallation addUniqueObject:@"Seur" forKey:@"channels"];
[currentInstallation addUniqueObject:@"ADIF" forKey:@"channels"];
[currentInstallation saveInBackground];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
currentInstallation.channels = @[ @"CocaCola", @"Seur", @"ADIF" ];
[currentInstallation saveInBackground];
```

Alternatively, look into using `subscribeToChannelInBackground`

> ### `subscribeToChannelInBackground:`
>
> Asynchronously subscribes the device to a channel of push notifications.
>
> `+ (void)subscribeToChannelInBackground:(NSString *)channel`